# How to get correct time using timestamp and timezone(in seconds) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

```js
const time = (dt, timeZone) => {
    const timestamp = dt;

    const milliseconds = timestamp * 1000
    const date = new Date(milliseconds);
    const offset = timezone/3600;
    const adjusted = milliseconds - offset * 60 * 1000;
    const local = new Date(adjusted);

    const options = {
        month: 'short',
        day: 'numeric',
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        hour12: true
    };
    const formattedDate = local.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
    return formattedDate;
};
```

`dt` and `timezone` will come from api response for every location searched.
`let dt=1690299297`, `timezone=-18000`. The code above is not printing correct time for every location, example time in London is 5:36 am but the code prints 2:32pm.

Comment: Change timeZone in `const time = (dt, timeZone) =>`  to timezone to match the name when you calculate offset.

Comment: if `1690299297` is seconds since 1 jan 1970 UTC, then it is NOT 5:36 or 2:32 anywhere, it's 15:34:57 UTC - also, what is `60 * 1000 * timezone / 3600` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const time = (dt, timeZone) => {

    const timestamp = dt;

    const milliseconds = timestamp * 1000
    const dateTime = new Date(milliseconds);
    const toUTC = dateTime.getTime() + dateTime.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000
    const currentLocalTime = toUTC + 1000 * timeZone;
    const selectedDate = new Date(currentLocalTime);
    const options = {
        month: 'short', 
        day: 'numeric',
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        hour12: true
    };
    const formattedDate = selectedDate.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
    return formattedDate;
};
```

I have made changes to the code, and now it correctly prints the time for certain locations. However, for some other locations, it displays the time as 5-6 minutes behind. The time format used is Jul 26, 10:30 AM